# How to run Lucene on Android?

Tags: java, android, lucene

I am trying to use the Apache Lucene library (9.9.1 version) in my Android application. Here are the relevant parts of my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
android {
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Lucene
    implementation("org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:9.9.1")

    // Core library desugaring
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4")
}
```

I am using Java 17 and desugaring the core library to get extended Java features as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Yet, when trying to use Lucene in the application, this line:

```kotlin
val indexDirectory: Directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath)
```

causes the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 2444
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method version()Ljava/lang/Runtime$Version; in class Ljava/lang/Runtime; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Runtime' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:40)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(FSDirectory.java:161)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(FSDirectory.java:156)
    ...
```

Method `java.lang.Runtime.version()` couldn't have been found...

From what I've read in the [requirements](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_9_1/SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS.html), Lucene runs on Java 11 or greater. This and the error suggest to me that the Java on Android is missing some features required to run Lucene - especially the 'version()' method from the error.

What can I do at this point? Should I downgrade Lucene to an Android-stable version (if there even is one)? Or is there some better approach that I'm not aware of? Please help!

**UPDATE:** I've tried replacing the version of Lucene with `8.11.2`, `7.7.3`, `6.6.6` and `5.5.5`. In all of these versions, the first error stopped happening, but another one started occuring:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Process: com.example.myapp PID: 5143
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/ClassValue;
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.createComponents(StandardAnalyzer.java:103)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:198)
    at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.tokenStream(Field.java:574)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:740)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:447)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:403)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:478)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1571)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1316)
    ...
```

Again, Android Java is missing something - this time the class `ClassValue`...

Apparently the [`ClassValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassValue) has been added in API 34 - no way I'm setting `minSdk` to 34.

Is there really no workaround for these issues on Android? Is Lucene just not compatible?

Comment: It doesn't look like it exists within Android - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime

Comment: Yeah, but I've seen people using Lucene on Android, so there has to be a workaround even if it means library version downgrade.

Comment: Looking at the source, version 8 might work as it uses a different method of resolving Java version. It also supports Java 8 so is probably a better option for Android.

Comment: @Philio I've updated the question in accordance with your recommendation.